# What is the shloka in the movie "Arjun: The Warrior Prince" during the marching of the battle and also while Arjun attacks in the end?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, shloka

I am including the two links for the part of movies, where the shloka is used:

Marching: https://youtu.be/ifKr5Nxf0wc?t=222

Attacking: https://youtu.be/H3-D6yeGJm8?t=25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [verse 2.31](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=ro&field_chapter_value=2&field_nsutra_value=31&etgb=1&setgb=1&choose=1) from the Bhagavad-gītā:

> स्वधर्ममपि चावेक्ष्य न विकम्पितुमर्हसि । 
>   धर्म्याद्धि युद्धाच्छ्रेयोऽन्यत्क्षत्रियस्य न विद्यते ॥ ३१ ॥
>
> sva-dharmam api cāvekṣya na vikampitum arhasi 
>   dharmyād dhi yuddhāc chreyo ’nyat kṣatriyasya na vidyate
>
> 2.31 Even considering your own duty you should not waver, since there is nothing else better for a Ksatriya than a righteous battle.
>
> (Translation By Swami Gambirananda)

Comment: Thank you very much.